# Moving Excel cells by click and drag in a Table - formatting is not always maintained

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

When I highlight a range of cells in a Table and drag it so that none of the new cell positions overlap the old cell positions, the formatting is maintained (which is just what I want). But when I click and drag it so there is an overlap between the new and old cell positions, the formatting for cells in that overlap region are discarded (see images below). How do I make it so the formatting stays no matter where I drag the cells?

[image: Before highlight & drag]

[image: After highlight & drag]

Comment: Try right-click-and-drag, then choose "Move" on the pop-up menu.

Comment: Same issue when I do this.

Comment: My Excel 2013 does not exhibit the behavior you're seeing... :-(

Comment: Try copy and paste special or cut and paste special

Comment: New piece of detail I forgot: my data region is inside a Table. Excel drags just fine when not inside a table for me. Is there a way to prevent this behavior for a table? @SuperSam: I cannot cut and paste special and copy & paste is too cumbersome since the original data needs to be deleted (we will be doing this many many times).